# Contents of a file_get_content() to process PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am need to use some PHP tags on a file(subfile) that is being called into a template using file_get_contents(Subfile).

I initially used require(subFile) instead of file_get_contents(). But it doesnt quite work as my content gets placed in the wrong spot. And also I can't change the template file to use require().

my template is something like this:

```
//TEMPLATE FILE.php
$html = file_get_contents(subFile); //I CAN NOT CHANGE  THIS FILE
```

Then my sub file, the one I can change.

```
//SUB FILE.php
<div>Hello world, today is <?php echo date($mydate);?> </div>
```

Because it is being called with file_get_contents(), it out puts

```
Hello world, today is <?php echo date($mydate);?>
```

Instead of:

```
Hello world, today is Thursday.
```

So, considering I can't change my `TEMPLATE FILE.php` where the file_get_content() is used.
I was thinking if there is a way that I can wrap the content of SUB FILE.php so it would process the PHP before allowing it to be called by the `TEMPLATE FILE.php`.

Something like this I am after

```
//SUB FILE.php
<force Process the PHP ?>
<div>Hello world, today is <?php echo date($mydate);?> </div>
<Finishe Force Process ?>
<allow it to be called via file_get_content();
```

If I could change the template file I could use htmlspecialchars_decode(); but I can't.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do that so I end up with this

```
ob_start();
$output = include (Dir/SubFile);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$html = $output; 

//$html = file_get_contents(subFile); The way it was
```

Comment: Can you access the subfile via the web server? Then you can do `file_get_contents("http://localhost/subFile.php");` and the PHP will be executed.

Comment: The problem is that I can't chnage the template file where the file_get_contents() happen. :(

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck. You can't fix this by changing the subfile, it has to be done in the script that uses it.

Comment: The template script is just reading the file, and reading a file doesn't execute it.

Comment: `file_get_contents` and `require` do two entirely different functions. you are literally reading through the file's data in the first one, whereas the second one adds the contents of the passed file's contents as PHP where it is included.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of the official manual

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
echo $homepage;
```

try this:

```
file_get_contents('http://YourDomain/Yoursubfile');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cann't use `<?php echo $a; ?>` to echo the content of variable $a.
Because you will get the plain html content from your subfile.

What you can do is to:-

Step1: my_date.php

```
<?php
$today = date('M-d-Y');
$subfile_html = file_get_contents(subFile);  //Path to my_date1.html or my_date1.php
echo $new_html_content = str_replace('{TODAYS_DATE}', $today, $subfile_html); // It will replace the occurance {TODAYS_DATE} with today's date

// OUTPUT:
// Hello world, today is June 20 2014
?>
```

Step2: my_date1.html or my_date1.php

```
<div> Hello world, today is {TODAYS_DATE} </div>
```